# DOM innerText loop for radio button

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom, radio-button

Is there a way to loop an innerText for radio buttons? I have the values in an array and I want to loop them as text to the radio button I'm looping in. I have a for-llop that is creating radio buttons with class and value, now I need to use the value as text to go with it. Like this:

```
<input type="radio" class="response" value="2">2
```

The code I have so far is:

```
let radioButtons = Object.values(questionAlternatives)

for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(questionAlternatives).length; i++) {
  let answerRadio = document.querySelector('#answerRadio')
  let radioButton = document.createElement('input')
  radioButton.setAttribute('type', 'radio')
  radioButton.setAttribute('class', 'response')
  radioButton.setAttribute('value', radioButtons[i])
  answerRadio.appendChild(radioButton)
}
```

Any way it could work?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after some digging:

```
for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(questionAlternatives).length; i++) {
  let answerRadio = document.querySelector('#answerRadio')
  let radioButton = document.createElement('input')
  let radioText = document.createTextNode(radioButtons[i].toString())
  radioButton.setAttribute('type', 'radio')
  radioButton.setAttribute('class', 'response')
  radioButton.setAttribute('value', radioButtons[i])
  answerRadio.appendChild(radioButton)
  answerRadio.appendChild(radioText)
}
```